# SQLite ORDER BY AND LIMIT Skips records

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to select records from SQLite DB using ORDER BY AND with limit. At a time I am expecting 1000 records. there are around 400k rows in the table. Once the record count reaches around 30 K, it starts skipping records. Record IDs are continuous from 1 to 400 000. When [LIMIT 29000, 1000] reaches, it gives records from ID 54001.

SQLite version 3.13.0
OS: Fedora release 24 (Twenty Four) x86_64

```
SELECT tab1.FID, tab1.NAME, tab2.NAME as TNAME, tab1.SIZE
FROM tab1
INNER JOIN tab2 ON tab2.DID = tab1.DID
WHERE (tab1.STATUS IN (0, 2, 4, 10) AND tab2.NAME LIKE "'/4L/%'")
ORDER BY tab1.FID ASC
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 29000
```

It is supposed to give results from 29001, but gives records from 54001.

Comment: *It is supposed to give results from 29001* if your query returned all the rows. But it does not because you have a WHERE clause and also you join to tab2. Are all `did`s of tab1 in tab2 too?

Answer (score 0):

Just a speculation, but perhaps you should limit first in a subquery, and then subquery to restrict again by status and name, e.g.:

```
SELECT FID, NAME, TNAME, SIZE
FROM
(
    SELECT tab1.FID, tab1.NAME, tab2.NAME as TNAME, tab1.SIZE
    FROM tab1
    INNER JOIN tab2
        ON tab2.DID = tab1.DID
    ORDER BY tab1.FID
    LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 29000
) t
WHERE STATUS IN (0, 2, 4, 10) AND NAME LIKE "'/4L/%'";
```

Comment: My query should be giving the same result, right? Any idea why this kind of behavior?

Comment: Not necessarily...your `WHERE` clause would be filtering off records _before_ the `LIMIT/OFFSET` gets applied.  My answer does not do this.

Comment: Works fine when all the records are with the status 0. Status became 1 for first 2000 records, then again started behaving strange.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question using sample data?  That would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: 996|'aa56dcaed491cf3e3d8606663c9c9cfb.cvs'|'/root/root/4L/88/'|32|0
997|'6577c7e5e0754178cd776c921b9276a2.cvs'|'/root/root/4L/88/'|32|0
998|'7ca7a76cb2bb3164b20322cee789928a.cvs'|'/root/root/4L/88/'|32|0
999|'b50ddf863f5ea193bedd5eb6bdc46542.cvs'|'/root/root/4L/88/'|32|0
1000|'482eb6f825b20347782cb460d758f909.cvs'|'/root/root/4L/88/'|32|0

When the last column (STATUS) is [0, 2, 4, 10], your query is working fine. Lets say, now the STATUS is 1 for records till 100000 and 100001 is having the status 0. In this case LIMIT 0, 1000 will not work, right?